# RMAN Config History

Tags: oracle, rman

I know this seems kind of a strange request, but does RMAN have any history of the changes to config parameters?    Seems like one of the team members has been changing the config parameters to a number of instances, and of course no one is claiming responsibility nor communicating with the team on why they are changing the parameters.

Is there any history on the changes?  Or, if we wanted to put some before update triggers in place, can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you save the rman backup log for every backup, then before backup - rman will push all current RMAN settings (identical to `rman> show all`) to that file, then backup result.
Just open daily rman log backup and compare, at least you will get the date of (some) rman settings has changed.
RMAN just keep notion of original (by `# default`), but don't mention when it was changed!